# How to call a http post method from a service in a parent director

Tags: angular8

My http method returns results when it is contained in my component, but does not return any results when called from a service located one directory up.

I've checked the console and there are no errors.  I have tried printing to the console, which works from within the service (returns the desired data), but does not when run from within the child component.

This is the service that I'm trying to build:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resturant } from '../../models/resturant.model'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetResturantsService {

  fullListresturants: Resturant[];


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  fetchList(){
    this.http.get('https://lunchlads.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
    .pipe(map(responseData =>{
      const postsArray: Resturant[] = [];
      for (const key in responseData) {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id:key })
        }
      }
      return postsArray;
    }))
    .subscribe(posts => {
      // this.fullListresturants = posts;
    });
  }


}
```

This is the component which is one file down in the directory:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Resturant } from '../../../models/resturant.model'
import { GetResturantsService } from '../get-resturants.service'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
//import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-all',
  templateUrl: './list-all.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-all.component.css']
})
export class ListAllComponent implements OnInit {
fullListresturants: Resturant;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private listAllResturants:GetResturantsService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.onfullList();
  }


  onfullList(){
    this.fullList();
  }

  private fullList(){
    // this.http.get('https://lunchlads.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
    // .pipe(map(responseData =>{
    //   const postsArray: Resturant[] = [];
    //   for (const key in responseData) {
    //     if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    //       postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id:key })
    //     }
    //   }
    //   return postsArray;
    // }))
    // .subscribe(posts => {
    //   // this.fullListresturants = posts;
    // });
    this.listAllResturants.fetchList();
  }

}
```

The firebase backend contains roughly 10 records with a name:string, votes:number, and selected:number fields.  When run from the component, the html file simply returns the name values with an *ngFor loop.

When run from the service, nothing is returned and no errors are reported in the console.

I suspect the problem lies somewhere in how I am calling the fetchList method from the component, but google and me have not been able to suss out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service should return an observable to make it work. As per your current code, you are not returning anything from `GetResturantsService.fetchList()`. To make it work let change the service like this:

```
export class GetResturantsService {

  fullListresturants: Resturant[];


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  fetchList(){
    return this.http.get('https://lunchlads.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
    .pipe(map(responseData =>{
      const postsArray: Resturant[] = [];
      for (const key in responseData) {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id:key })
        }
      }
      return postsArray;
    }));        
  }
}
```

Now in component subscribe to the observable returned from `fetchList` method like this:

```
export class ListAllComponent implements OnInit {
fullListresturants: Resturant;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private listAllResturants:GetResturantsService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.onfullList();
  }


  onfullList(){
    this.fullList();
  }

  private fullList(){

    this.listAllResturants.fetchList()
         .subscribe(posts => {
               //DO whatever you want to do with posts
               this.fullListresturants = posts;
          });
  }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Looks like I need to dig in further on observables.  Thank you for your help.